# PowerMockIgnore all package except one class

Tags: powermock

Is there any way to annotate @PowerMockIgnore to ignore the whole package except just one class inside this package?

I was hoping to do something like for example:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "foo.bar.ignore*\DoNotIgnoreClass"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@PrepareForTest` annotation:

e.g.

```
@PrepareForTest(DoNotIgnoreClass.class)
```

or for multiple classes:

```
@PrepareForTest({DoNotIgnoreClass.class, Another.class})
```